# How to clone ACL permissions?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, acl

I've just found out that my backups were missing ACL and the restore will not work until this is fixed.

Luckily I have the luxury of checking what the permissions should look like on a running system, e.g:

RESTORED:

```
# file: samba/sysvol
# owner: root
# group: 3000000
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

RUNNING:

```
# file: samba/sysvol
# owner: root
# group: 3000000
user::rwx
user:root:rwx
group::rwx
group:3000000:rwx
group:3000001:r-x
group:3000002:rwx
group:3000003:r-x
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:root:rwx
default:group::---
default:group:3000000:rwx
default:group:3000001:r-x
default:group:3000002:rwx
default:group:3000003:r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

There are no trivial permissions patterns to follow so manual reconciliation would take very long and be error prone.

QUESTION:

Is it possible to "clone" ACL permissions?

I.e. recursively read ACL (getfacl?) on all files and folders and write (setacl?) to the same list of files and folders elsewhere?

Answer (score 3):

If source and destination are both locally or you can copy between them over SSH or rsync protocol you can use `rsync -A` to copy ACL between directories.

This will copy ACL locally on same machine.

```
rsync -Ar dir1/ dir2/
```

If both servers have compatible ACL you can use it to copy ACL over network without actually copying files over again.

```
rsync -Ar /dir1/ user@destination:/dir2/
```

or

```
rsync -Ar user@source:/dir1/ /dir2/
```

depending on which server you are running command.

From rsync manpages:

> -A, --acls
>             This option causes rsync to update the destination ACLs to be the same as the source ACLs.  The option also implies --perms.
>
> The source and destination systems must have compatible ACL entries
>   for this option to work properly.  See the --fake-super option for a
>   way to backup and restore ACLs that are not compatible.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply rAlen. I ended up using: `getfacl -R source_dir > file` followed by `setfacl --restore file destination_dir`

Comment: While `-Ar` preserves ACLs, it doesn't preserves ownerships and permissions. Use `-Arogp` (_o=owner, g=group, p=permissions_) or shorter and more common `-Ara` (_a=archive_) for a better copy of your directory.

Comment: @CraZ No point in adding the -r if -a is present since -a is equivalent to -rlptgoD

Comment: @kl0z, true, the `-r` option is redundant (just forgot to remove it), correct options are `-Aa`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a single command to duplicate a directory with ownership,permissions,ACLs without recursively copying the contents. I ended up with a multi command solution involving mkdir, chown, chmod, setfacl, getfacl :-)

```
proj=project1
srcbase="/mydata"
destbase="/archive/mydata"
if [ ! -d $destbase/$proj ]; then
  echo "Cloning properties of $srcbase/$proj to $destbase/$proj"
  mkdir $destbase/$proj
  chown --reference=$srcbase $destbase/$proj
  chmod --reference=$srcbase $destbase/$proj
  cd $srcbase
  getfacl $proj > /tmp/${proj}.acl
  cd -
  cd $destbase
  setfacl --restore /tmp/${proj}.acl
  cd -
else
  echo "Archive directory already exists, skipping: $destbase"
fi
unset proj srcbase destbase
```

Perhaps there's a way to do this with rsync by telling it not to travers the directory...

Comment: Ha, found my notes from a few years ago, using Rsync to duplicate a directory without the contents:

rsync -a -s -A -X -f '- /*/*/' /source/dir /destination